# How to find missing dates AND missing period in sql table within a given range?

Tags: sql, database

Suppose there exist a table called:
**RandomPriceSummary** , which has the date ranging from **Wed Oct 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100** to **Wed Oct 03 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100**, and period ranging from **1-3** and cost as shown below:

| date | period | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wed Oct **01** 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) | 1 | 10 |
| Wed Oct **01** 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) | 2 | 20 |
| Wed Oct **01** 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) | 3 | 10 |
| Wed Oct **03** 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) | 1 | 20 |
| Wed Oct **03** 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) | 2 | 20 |

In the above table, how can we check all of the missing dates and missing periods?

For example, we need a query `WHERE SETTLEMENT_DATE BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '10-01-2022' AND TIMESTAMP '10-03-2022'` which has a missing period ranging from 1-3.
So the expected answer should return something along the lines of :

| missing_date | missing_period |
| --- | --- |
| Wed Oct **02** 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) | 1 |
| Wed Oct **02** 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) | 2 |
| Wed Oct **02** 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) | 3 |
| Wed Oct **03** 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time) | 3 |

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: The general solution is to have or generate ALL of the periods you want to check against and compare that to this table.  You can do that by storing the periods in another table, or by using some trick to generate an arbitrary number of rows from a connect by recursion or from a known large table's rownums or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following calendar table left anti-join approach:

```sql
SELECT d.dt, p.period
FROM (SELECT date_trunc('day', dd)::date AS dt
      FROM generate_series(
          '2022-01-01'::timestamp,
          '2022-12-31'::timestamp,
          '1 day'::interval) dd
) d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS period UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) p
LEFT JOIN RandomPriceSummary t
    ON t.date::date = d.dt AND t.period = p.perio
WHERE d.dt BETWEEN '2022-10-01'::date AND '2022-10-03'::date AND
      t.date IS NULL
ORDER BY d.dt, p.period;
```

Comment: How is this querying for the dates in the range of '10-01-2022' AND TIMESTAMP '10-03-2022'?

Comment: @constantlyFlagged Sorry I left out the date range restriction.

Comment: Yes, I can rewrite it using `generate_series()` ... give me a few minutes.

Comment: there is a typo "UN3ION" and "perio" meant to be "UNION" and "period". I cant edit, it since it is less than 6 characters ( rule set by stackoverflow)

Comment: Typo fixed, please check.